# Possible scenarios to justify heap-allocated variables scoped locally?

Tags: c++

I encountered the following code snippet.

```
int main() {
    auto a = new A(/* arguments */);
    // Do something
    delete a;
}
```

Here `A` is a very nontrivial class I cannot easily reason about (highly parallelized and networking involved). Because `x` is instantiated in `main` (or possibly any other function) and then deleted at the end of the scope, I thought there is no reason to heap allocate this variable `a`. Instead, I would simply instantiate it as a stack variable as `A a(/* */)`.

However, I wonder if there are any valid reasons to allocate `A` dynamically. One thing that comes to my mind is the possibility of saving some space in stack if `A` is a massive object, while I doubt that this would really make sense with modern machines.

Comment: Yes, object size is a valid reason for heap storage. Another one might be possibility of ownership transfer and lifetime management (although C++11 changed that with move semantics), see Qt for instance.

Comment: Even on "modern machines" with gigabytes of RAM, the stack is limited. For example, MSVC only allocates 1 MB of stack by default.

Comment: Object might use custom allocation functions or size of the object (array) might not be known at compile time.

Comment: [let's see what the C++ Core Guidelines have to say on the matter](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r5-prefer-scoped-objects-dont-heap-allocate-unnecessarily)

Comment: While there are reasons to allocate a locally scoped variable on the free store I don't see any reason here for the explicit use of `new`/`delete`.  Something like `auto a = std::make_unique<A>(/* arguments */)` would be preferable.

Comment: Some objects are required to be dynamically allocated. For example objects that inherit from `shared_from_this` need to be created using `make_shared`.  Usually in these cases they should only be constructible through a factory function (their constructor would be inaccessible). In any case you still shouldn't have to use `new` to create objects. Use smart pointers.

Comment: In our company C++ code base, which is originally inspired from Objective-C, we *always* `new` objects, even if locally used. But nearly every time, we create *autoreleased* objects (same concept as in Objective-C), that got destroyed automatically at pool destruction.

Comment: One reason would be to give it a polymorphic use.

Comment: Except that I don't think that's a good way to allocate an object on the heap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is no reason to not use a smart pointer here, i.e.

```
auto a = std::make_unique<A>(/* arguments */);
```

but as to why you would want to heap allocate rather than creating the object on the stack, reasons include

1. Size. Class A might be huge. Stack space is not inexhaustible; heap space is much much larger. Seriously, you can overflow the stack surprisingly easily, even on modern machines. You don't want to stack allocate an array of 100,000 items, etc.
2. You might need a pointer for runtime polymorphism. Say instead of calling A's constructor directly you are calling some factory function that returns a unique_ptr to a base class from which A inherits and the rest of your code depends on polymorphic calls to `a`; you'd need to use dynamic allocation in that case.